# How is the CoW Protocol price vector for the auction computed?

Tags: cow-protocol

When querying the `/auction` endpoints the response contains a price vector for each token. How is this price vector generated? What price estimators are used? What happens if only one of those price estimators have liquidity and fails to respond to the request?

Answer (score 1):

These prices are also called "external prices" and "native prices".

To find the native price of a token we ask price estimators to estimate a buy order selling the token to buy a configured native token amount. From the responses of all price estimators, we use the best one (the one selling as little as possible).

The native token amount and the native price estimators are configurable and change as we see fit. Currently on mainnet the amount is 1 ETH and the estimators used are ZeroEx, Quasimodo, Baseline, and Yearn (We used to also have Paraswap and Balancer but they are currently disabled).

In terms of choosing the best price estimator, we take the best price we get. If no price estimator can respond then there is no native price for this token and orders selling or buying this token won't be included in the auction.